# How to access controls of Multilayer Panels in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, controls, panel, multi-layer

I want to access all of the controls in my form with this code:

For each pc in Myform.control

do somthing

My Problem is that I have multilayer panels in myform.For example "Myform" contains (textbox1,textbox 2,combobox1,panle1,panel2).

Panel1 contains (panel11 and textbox 3)

panel 2 contains (panel22 and textbox4 and combobox2)

In addition panel22 contains (textbox5 and panle222)

How can I access "All" of the controls(textbox and combobox) in "Myform" without considering whether they are in a panel or not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask you why you need this?

Comment: I want to insert values into textboxes and comboboxes dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Private Sub EnumerateControl(parentControl As Control)
    For Each child As Control In parentControl.Controls
        Debug.WriteLine(child.Name)
        If child.HasChildren Then EnumerateControl(child)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then call this to use it:

```
EnumerateControl(Me) 'Pass the form control to start the enumeration
```

The key here is to test if the control in question has children and if so enumerate all controls in that control by calling `EnumerateControl` recursively

Comment: Why pass ByRef? That shouldn't make any difference in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them in a recursive way such as:

```
Public Sub ProcessControls(ByRef Controls As ControlCollection)
    For Each pc As Control In Controls
        'Do whathever you want

        If pc.Controls.Count Then 'If that control has child, process them
            ProcessControls(pc.Controls)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```